# search for int id starting with x entity framework 4.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I currently have an Entity Framework model that collects data from a legacy database and I am currently using an `int` on my `Id` properties

I am attempting to build a search box with autocomplete capabilities and want to have the autocomplete function to return a subset of records based on whether the sample `id` either contains or starts with (final design decision not made yet)  and I am running into problems with converting the integer `id` to a string as I would normally use a `recs.Id.toString().StartsWith(recordId)`   but this is apparently not supported by the Entity Framework

Is there a way around this limitation ?

My code looks like the following

Model:

```
public class Sample
{
  public Sample()
  {
      Tests = new List<Test>();
  }

public          int                     Id              { get; set; }
public          DateTime                SampleDate      { get; set; }
public          string                  Container       { get; set; }
public          string                  Product         { get; set; }
public          string                  Name            { get; set; }
public          string                  Status          { get; set; }

public virtual SamplePoint SamplingPoint { get; set; }
public virtual SampleTemplate SampleTemplate { get; set; }
public Customer ForCustomer { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Test> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

and the query I am currently trying to apply to this model

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string partialId)
{
    var filteredSamples = 
                repo.AllSamples.Where( s =>                                   
                                String.Compare(s.Status, "A", false) == 0
                                && (s.Id.ToString()).StartsWith(partialId)
                        ).ToList();

    return Json(filteredSamples, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Any ideas would be awesome I am out of ideas at this point

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717253/how-do-i-query-an-integer-column-for-starts-with-in-entity-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up adding a view for autocomplete data and converting the data to string in the select statement and this solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

No matter what you do, this is going to result in some awful performance on large datasets, because you will not be able to use any indices.  My recommendation would be to use a trigger or scheduled task to store the leading digit in a separate field and filter on that.

Comment: ya it is using a database with over 1mil+ records in the database it is already stored as a string value (oracle) and is indexed but no official prjmary key exists i may  simply create a view for the ids only should improve the performance on this

Comment: If you change it to store the ID as a string, then leading-character (or trailing-character, depending on the database) wildcard searches would work, but contains will still generate a table scan.  Relational databases in general do not deal well with packed column data.

Answer (score 0):

Wild thought: how about your create a **computed, persisted column** on your database table, that converts your `ID` (`INT`) into a string?

Then you could:

- put an index on that column
- use a simple string comparison on that string column

Basically, you need this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ADD IDAsText AS CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED
```

Now update you EF model - and now you should have a new `string` field `IDAsText` in your object class. Try to run your autocomplete comparisons against that string field.

Comment: i unfortunately cant make changes to the database due to liscencing restrictions in the support contract we are currently pulling custom reporting data into a view on a seperate schema  but in the database as i mentioned above already is a indexed string column i was using an integer datatype on the model only   i way revisit this decision in a future version of our data api but for now this will have to be  kept as is  the view is working well so far and is able to filter the records in about 180ms which is fast enough for the way im pulling them out for the auto complete