# How do I query an integer column for "starts with" in Entity Framework?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, search, ef-code-first

I have a column that's defined as an integer in EF (Code First).  I want to search it using "starts with." Now, I can do this:

```
Where(x => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.AccountNumber).StartsWith(searchTerm))
```

However, `SqlFunctions.StringConvert()` gets translated to the T-SQL function `STR()`, which left-pads the result for reasons which are beyond my comprehension.

Also, I can't use `string.TrimStart()` because it's not supported by the Entity Framework.

Can anyone lend any help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Trim()` and `TrimStart()` work in LINQ to Entities, so you can use:

```
Where(x => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.AccountNumber)
    .TrimStart().StartsWith(searchTerm))
```

`TrimStart` translates into `LTRIM` in SQL. With `searchTerm` = 123 for example you get something like:

```
WHERE LTRIM(STR( CAST( [Extent1].[AccountNumber] AS float))) LIKE N'123%'
```

Comment: What about in EF Core 3+ ?