# Integer Contains Using Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, casting

I'm having some difficulty writing a linq query that will check whether the consecutive digits in an integer are contained in the primary key of a table.  So, suppose there is a table called `Employees` with a primary key on the column `Employees.Id`.  Suppose this primary key is of Sql Server datatype `INT`.  I would like to write a linq query using Entity Framework Code First that will return all employees whose primary key contains the string 456.  Something like:

```
string filter = "456";

var results = from e in myDbContext.Employees
  where e.Id.Contains(filter)
  select e;
```

The problem is that the Contains method is not offered for integer datatypes in C#...

Comment: FYI string.Contains() is not an extension method, but is a regular method on string objects.

Comment: @recursive:  Thanks, I've edited the question to include your correction.

Comment: Even though X.L.Ant has offered a solution, you may want to consider changing the datatype of your column to `char` or `varchar`. The purpose of a numeric type is to store and process the *magnitude* of a value, which is why an `int` type has built-in functions such as "greater than" and "less than". If the individual symbols in your ID have actual meaning, then what you are storing is atually a *code*, which happens to use numeric symbols, but does not represent a magnitude.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try:

```
var results = from e in myDbContext.Employees
  where SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)e.Id).Contains(filter)
  select e;
```

Comment: Are you sure `ToString()` call will be translated into SQL?

Comment: I get an error saying "Linq to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: @X.L.Ant:  Thanks, your solution works great!  I'm just waiting for Stack Overflow's clock to elapse another minute so that I can accept your answer:)

Comment: I'm using this function with StartsWith and it doesn't return any values, whereas contains will return values. I know StartsWith should return values so the query is not executing correctly. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @CSharper Maybe `TrimStart()` (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717253/how-do-i-query-an-integer-column-for-starts-with-in-entity-framework)) can help you.

Comment: Works well. Complete Namsepace comes like this: System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlFunctions

Answer (score 8):

You can convert both to string and then do the query. In your case:

`string filter = "456";
var results = from e in myDbContext.Employees
  where e.Id.ToString().Contains(filter)
  select e;`

Comment: does `ToString()` throws an exception of type `NotSupportedException` ?

Comment: This works for me (Entity Framework Core 6). SqlFunctions doesn't exist, might be because I'm using SQLite.