# Integer contains linq c# but using using expressions

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I want to create a dynamic filter for my repositories using linq expressions, I have other filters but i don't know how to make the next one using expressions: (the condition was taked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17110850/integer-contains-using-linq))

```
var result = _studentRepotory.GetAll().Where(s => 
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)s.Id).Contains("91")).ToList();
```

I have a method that receives the value of a property, the propertyName and the filter operator type (enum):

```
public static class Helper {
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(object value, string propertyName, FilterOperatorType FilterType)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var property = ExpressionUtils.GetPropertyChild(parameter, propertyName);
        var constValue = Expression.Constant(value);

        BinaryExpression expresion = null;
        switch (FilterType)
        {
            case FilterOperatorType.Equal:
                expresion = Expression.Equal(property, constValue);
                break;
            case FilterOperatorType.Greater:
                expresion = Expression.GreaterThan(property, constValue);
                break;
            case FilterOperatorType.Less:
                expresion = Expression.LessThan(property, constValue);
                break;
            case FilterOperatorType.GreaterOrEqual:
                expresion = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(property, constValue);
                break;
            case FilterOperatorType.LessOrEqual:
                expresion = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(property, constValue);
                break;
        }

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(expresion, parameter);
        return lambda;
    }
}
```

So, I want to add a new opertator type **Contains** that will evaluate if an integer contains some digits, in the first block of code I do it, but I want to do it with linq expressions using generics.

At the end I wil have:

```
Expression<Func<Student, bool>> where = Helper.GetExpression<Student>("91", "Id",  FilterOperatorType.Contains);
var result = _studentRepotory.GetAll().Where(where).ToList();
```

The query should return all the students when the Id contains the digits 91.

Please help me, and tell me if you understand.

Comment: There's no out of box way, you need to create a `MethodCallExpression`

Comment: do google search for a `predicatebuilder` library/class. i've used this one recently: https://gist.github.com/anomepani/243a817216f90c45b7c9ad2bd24ccb66#file-predicatebuilder-cs

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I have other filter for strings and I user Expression.Call but I dont know how to do this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm at 2:00 am and still working on this, the brain works better at that time hehehe, here is the solution for create the expression:

```
object value = "91";

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Student));
var property = ExpressionUtils.GetPropertyChild(parameter, "Id");
var constValue = Expression.Constant(value);

var expressionConvert = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(double?));

var methodStringConvert = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("StringConvert",
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, null,
                    CallingConventions.Any,
                    new Type[] { typeof(double?) },
                    null);

var methodContains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance,
            null, CallingConventions.Any,
            new Type[] { typeof(String) }, null);

var expresionStringConvert = Expression.Call(methodStringConvert, expressionConvert);
var expresionContains = Expression.Call(expresionStringConvert, methodContains, constValue);
var lambdaContains = Expression.Lambda<Func<Student, bool>>(expresionContains, parameter);
```

Now you can use lambdaContains in the Where method of the studentRepository

Comment: What is `SqlFunctions` is it a custom class. You can solve more complex use cases using the extension methods on `string` and using `string`or `List<string>` or similar Data structure as input. In extension methods you can solve more complex use cases, but just that it needs to be used in same memory or otherwise use an Expression Serializer

Comment: @MrinalKamboj SqlFunctions is a static class from the EntityFramework package with helpers functions. [View reference here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlFunctions.cs)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method. And you can search int columns as strings

https://gist.github.com/gnncl/e424adefc3e08b607beee8d638759492