# TrimStart in Expression Tree with LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression-trees

I'm attempting to write an expression tree which can allow dynamic use of a `StartsWith()` method on non-string valued columns using Entity Framework.

E.g. `IntegerValuedColumn.StartsWith(5)` would return `500`, `5000`, `555`, `5123`, etc

I am trying to write an expression tree based on this answer:

[How do I query an integer column for "starts with" in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7717253/how-do-i-query-an-integer-column-for-starts-with-in-entity-framework)

Here is what I have so far:

```
MethodInfo stringConvert = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("StringConvert", new[] { typeof(double?) });

Expression castExpression = Expression.Convert(propertyExpression, typeof(double?));

Expression convertExpression = Expression.Call(null, stringConvert, castExpression);

MethodInfo trimStart = typeof(string).GetMethod("TrimStart");

Expression nullExpression = Expression.Constant(null, typeof(char[]));
Expression trimExpression = Expression.Call(convertExpression, trimStart, nullExpression);

MethodInfo startsWith = typeof(string).GetMethod("StartsWith", new[] { typeof(string) });

Expression methodExpression = Expression.Call(trimExpression, startsWith, constantExpression);

return methodExpression;
```

When I compile and run this expression, I get the following exception:

**The method 'System.String TrimStart(Char[])' is only supported in LINQ to Entities when there are no trim characters specified as arguments.**

In the original example, the expression is:

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)x.AccountNumber)
    .TrimStart().StartsWith(searchTerm)
```

But what I get comes out as:

```
StringConvert(Convert(x.AccountNumber)).TrimStart(null).StartsWith(searchTerm)
```

I have removed the two lines dealing with TrimStart (nullExpression and trimExpression) and verified that the statement runs (excluding the thought that the error is being caused by the different language use). My theory based on the exception message is that the TrimStart() method wants to be called with zero parameters, but when I try that the Expression builder tells me that the incorrect number of parameters have been passed in so I figure I'm just missing something.

How would I go about calling the TrimStart method like `TrimStart()` instead of `TrimStart(null)` or `TrimStart(new char[0])` using expression trees?

Comment: `TrimStart()` means `TrimStart(new char[0])` in regular C# code. I don't mean they have the same effect, I mean they compile to the exact same IL. You can't have `TrimStart()` unless you have `TrimStart(new char[0])`. But why do you need to trim at all? If you convert a number to a string, it doesn't (by default) contain any spacing, right?

Comment: Looks like a bug in EF. Can you use `Trim`? That has a () overload.

Comment: @usr Not a bug, an unimplemented feature where the exception message spells out what is and isn't currently supported.

Comment: @hvd he's not specifying any characters (he's giving null which is statically known to EF). He is complying with what the message says. TrimStart has no empty overload, btw.

Comment: @usr But like I said, `TrimStart()` means `TrimStart(new char[0])` (its parameter is a `params` array). It doesn't mean `TrimStart(null)`.

Comment: @hvd he should try new char[0] then. The message (`no trim characters specified`) does not say which of the two is allowed. If new char[0] works, the message is unhelpful/wrong (I understand both interpretations). If new char[0] is not working, the message is clearly wrong. Wrong messages are bugs.

Comment: @usr That's a fair point. I think the message is intended to be read as simply "don't pass any arguments", but you're right, that's not what it says.

Comment: @usr, using Trim() instead worked perfectly. Thanks a ton! Doesn't quite fix the problem posed in the original question, but solves the issue I was having.

Comment: I know this was posted a loong time ago but it would help if you provided your solution. I am facing the same issue but I want to use `Trim()`.

Comment: Definitely was a long time ago. I'm pretty sure I ended up just replacing the TrimStart() with Trim() and it worked fine like that.